# How to display html action as string in mvc 3 razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-view-controller

I am using @Html.Action to call contoller action to return a string. I want to save the string to a variable inside razor as it is comma-seperated.

```
@Html.Action("GetCategories", new { SP = @ViewBag.Name, SD = "Cad" }).ToString();
//@String s = save above string in here
//@string[] arrS = s.Split(','); 

@String test = @Html.Action(......) //tried this but does NOT work.

Public ActionResult GetCategories(string SP, string SD)
{
  //Code missing
  return Content(return "sugar");
}
```

How can I save the Html.Action returned data to a string ?

Comment: try this. @String test = "@Html.Action(......)";

Comment: does not work gives error: 'string' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: This: `@{string test = Html.Action("SomeAction").ToString();}` works for me in MVC5 (sorry get test under MVC3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, just tried in a local MVC project:

```
@{
      string test;
      test = @Url.Action("actionName");          
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Url.Action only/always returns a Url.  Not sure how this selected answer solved the problem for you unless you DID want the Url (e.g. /Controller/Action/...).

Seems Html.Action was what you wanted all along.  It would return the contents "sugar" if you simply had your return coded like this;

return Content("sugar");

You can display it right on the page or use the suggested syntax from "Mark" to save it to a varible